# iOS call a number with # and *?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to make a call to a number which is in format:

***411*4567394415177895*10#**

which is for recharging (topup) of balance in network.

I used following block of code for this:

```
NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",_textField.text]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
    NSLog(@"Can Call");
} else
{
    NSLog(@"Can't Call");
}
```

It prints out the "can call" text which means that the url is correct and should direct me to the phone app in iOS but it stays in same screen.